# Flask webserver with React client and RestFull API

Tags: reactjs, flask, routes, blueprint

How are you?

I'm trying to maintain two services on the same flask web server: A React client (available in "/*") and a RestFull API (available in "/api/*").

However, all routes are directed to the client and I cannot register the Blueprint to "/api".

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ""})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def client_route(path):
    return 'Client'


app.register_blueprint(routes, url_prefix="/api")
""" Registro de rotas da aplicação """
```

[printscreen code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsOs6.png)

I need routes starting with "/api" to call the API routes, while all other routes (*) call Client React.

Can anybody help me??

Answer (score 1):

main_view.py

> bp = Blueprint('main', **name**, url_prefix='/api')

app.py

> app.register_blueprint(main_view.bp)

When setting the blue print, enter '/api' instead of 'prefix = /' section.  oh You've already set it up like that, but in my case  I write above .

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You must enter `api` not `\api`.

Here is a link on how blueprints work: https://realpython.com/flask-blueprint/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

You just need to swap the order of the register, like that:

```
app.register_blueprint(routes, url_prefix="/api")
""" Registro de rotas da aplicação """


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ""})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def client_route(path):
    if path != "" and os.path.exists(app.static_folder + '/' + path):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')
```

(*) And you may use this React code to serve the webapp correctly.

Thaks!!

Comment: Glad to hear and sorry our solutions did not help ):